# Firefox 62.0.3 (64-bit) overrides address typed into address bar (OS X 10.12.6)

Tags: firefox, browser, url, django

I'm working on a Django website project and have come across peculiar behavior in Firefox that I need a work-around for.

I'm attempting to reach `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` in order to reach a locally-hosted copy of my web project. This should be fairly trivial. I type it into the browser bar and hit enter. However, I get taken to a different web address, `http://127.0.0.1:8000/sa/login/associate/` upon pressing enter. This address does not belong to my current project; it belongs to another project I'm working on. I have run `sudo lsof -i tcp:8000` to see if the web server for the other project is running; it is not.

It would seem as if Firefox is trying to be "helpful" by appending the rest of the web address from a web address in my browser history. I have switched off the browser history suggestion setting:

[image: FF settings]

What do I do to keep Firefox from overriding my input?
EDIT:

I have also switched **browser.fixup.alternate.enabled** in `about:config` to **False** to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing cache and cookies resolves this issue. Go to the Preferences page, then to Privacy and Security. Scroll to the History heading, then hit the Clear History button. This brings up a window with check boxes of what you want deleted. I only selected cache and cookies.

Source: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1044209